# `docker cp` fails when executed within a script

Tags: bash, docker, docker-cp

I have a bash script that does a few things, one of which is to `docker cp` a file to the host.

When I issue that command (without variable expansion) on the command line, the command works. It works with variable expansion on the command line as well. But the command fails in a script; even if that script is on the command line.

The command in the script is:

```
docker cp ${container_variable}:/some/path/file_name-${date_tag}.zip /host/path
```

When i try this in a command line script:

```
for file in `docker exec container ls -1 file_name*`
do
   docker cp container:/some/path/$file .
done
```

I get this (there are four such files that match that wildcard):

```
Error response from daemon: Could not find the file file_name-1.zip in container container
Error response from daemon: Could not find the file file_name-2.zip in container container
Error response from daemon: Could not find the file file_name-3.zip in container container
Error response from daemon: Could not find the file file_name-4.zip in container container
```

I just cannot figure out what the issue is here. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have `/some/path/` on the command line, but not in the script

Comment: ah, yes. That's a mistake. The path is there in the for script too. Can I edit my question?

Comment: It's a good idea to use actual commands and scripts when asking questions so you ensure that no mistakes creep in as you write your question.

Comment: Yes. I apologise.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?  Can you use a Docker bind mount to push part of your host filesystem into the container, and avoid `docker cp`?  Or would it make more sense to run the process directly on the host, and not in an isolated container?

Comment: That might be a solution right there. Bind a location on the host and do the copy in the container. Since it's a bind mount, it would be visible to the host too. I'll try that report my results.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`docker cp` command uses root directory. From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/cp/#description):

> The docker cp command assumes container paths are relative to the
> container's / (root) directory.

While `docker exec` uses current working directory ([`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#workdir)).

So the solution should be to look up what is the workdir in your docker container and add that to your copied path:

```bash
for file in `docker exec container ls -1 file_name*`
do
   docker cp container:/some/path/$file .
done
```

Comment: This sounds like you're referring to the Dockerfile. My issue is with the docker cli and a bash script. Unless you were talking about in the for script - that was a mistake to leave out the path. I used the path there too.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by just mounting a directory into the container and accessing the file directly on the host. Thanks to David Maze for the suggestion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).